# Laravel Excel ErrorException Undefined offset: 0

Tags: excel, laravel, import, import-from-excel, laravel-excel

Trying to import excel data to my mysql db and getting ErrorException Undefined offset: 0.

Tried using var_dump($row) to check the array of the row of the data. It looks off and not sure how to make the data shows nicely so that able to pass to db.

```
array(5) { ["a"]=> string(1) "B" ["white"]=> string(5) "Green" ["example1_at_gmailcom"]=> string(18) "example2@gmail.com" [60123456789]=> int(60162313142) [5]=> int(5) }
```

**This is my excel data:**

[image]

**Model**

```
 public function model(array $row)
{
    var_dump($row);
    return new ContactList([
        'first_name' => $row[0],
        'last_name' => $row[1],
        'email' => $row[2],
        'phone' => $row[3],
        'group_id' => $row[4],
    ]);
}
```

I already tried using replacing the $row[] with string and it works perfectly storing the data into my db.

**Controller**

```
if($request->hasFile('selected_file')){

            $file = $request->file('selected_file');
            Excel::import(new ContactListsImport, $file);


            return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Data saved successfully!');
        }
```

Comment: you are dumping the array you are getting ... do you see a key `0` in it?

Comment: sry, i am new to this. No i didnt see it but even i removed the vardump i still getting the same error ErrorException
Undefined offset: 0

Comment: because there is no index `0` as you can see as you dumped the array and there is no key `0` ... you can't access keys of an array that don't exist ... you have an issue here as the first row of this file is being used as the headers (column names), you should look into the documentation to adjust this or not use this behavior

Comment: Just an FYI, but Laravel using Symfony's VarDumper component so you can use [dump()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-dump) and [dd()](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-dd) for a more readable output.

Comment: What version of Laravel and Laravel Excel are you using?

Comment: 6.18.35  and 3.1

Comment: thanks using dd() the array looking great but it still getting error

Comment: Yeah, I didn't think `dd()` would solve anything :) Please can you show all the code in your `ContactListsImport` class.

Comment: I already found the way of doing it. Thks to lagbox's hint. Also thanks for letting me know using dd() for readable output

Comment: previously no and then i added header for column name mentioned by lagbox. So is the problem with the WithHeadingRow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the `WithHeadingRow` interface from your Import class to use numeric indexes for the array.

As per the [documentation](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/heading-row.html), when your Import class implements `WithHeadingRow` it will use the first row for the indexes of the array and in turn remove it from the rows that are provided.

Comment: Yes, I think this is the reason why

Comment: @N.Tec If this has answered your question please may you mark it as accepted :)